# How to define constant with folder path with back one step directory

Tags: php

I defined a constant (my folder path):

```
define('BASE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));
$targetDir = BASE_PATH.'/video_home_page';
```

This outputs:

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/manager/video_home_page`

What do I need to do to make `video_home_page` folder on `myproject` directly not in manager like this:

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/video_home_page`

How I can do this?

Comment: Use `@mkdir` to create directory! Let me know if you want more hepls!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just go up one directory before *video_home_page* like this:

```
$targetDir = BASE_PATH.'/../video_home_page';
```